# Castle configuration for Service with callback

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor, wcffacility

Here is my castle config in win forms client

```
<components>
    <component id="TestServiceClient"
               type="TcpService.ITestService, TcpService"
               wcfEndpointConfiguration="TestServiceClient_endpoint"/>
</components>
```

The question is how can i setup my config to support DuplexClientModel?
I can do this only via code as below.

```
        DuplexClientModel model = new DuplexClientModel
        {
            Endpoint = WcfEndpoint.ForContract<ITestServiceWithCallback>()
                .BoundTo(new NetTcpBinding())
                .At("net.tcp://localhost/TestServiceWithCallback")
        }.Callback(callbackService);
```

Comment: I also got stuck on this one, so be interested to see what answers you get.